# Making thick horizontal lines and a thick vertical line in a table

Tags: tables

I have the code for a table. What is the default thickness for the lines?  I would like to double the thickness for the vertical line to distinguish the "total column", and I would like to double the thickness for the horizontal line to distinguish the "total row." (I guess that I should make the line separating the title thicker, too.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c | c | c ||} \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|| c ||}{{\bf Residents of Preston City}} \\ \hline
        &   Employed    &   Unemployed  &   Total \\ \hline
Men     &   27,000      &               &          \\ \hline
Women   &               &               &   21,500 \\ \hline
Total   &   48,000      &               &   50,500 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{\fill} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about just using a [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) approach?

Comment: I agree with @Werner. Consider getting rid of the vertical rules and most of the horizontal ones. The table will be *more* readable (although I understand why people think it's the opposite).

Comment: @Alenanno  I am making a review for a standardized test.  The rows and columns on this standardized test are always separated by horizontal and vertical lines.  (I did look at the web site that Werner referenced.  Now I know that making thicker lines on a table cannot be done with LaTeX.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use  `makecell`, which has `\Xhline{thickness}` and `\Xcline{thickness}{col1-col2}` commands.

Alternatively, the `boldline` package, from the `shipunov` bundle, has `\hlineB`and `\clineB` commands; the argument is `num` times  `\arrayrulewidth`. It also has a `V{num}` specifier for vertical rules, which replaces `|`.

By the way, the default `\arrayrulewidth` is `0.4pt`.

Demo of both solutions:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{boldline}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{|| c | c | c !{\vrule width0.8pt}c ||}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|| c ||}{{\bf Residents of Preston City}} \\
    \hline
          & Employed & Unemployed & Total \\
    \hline
    Men & 27,000 & & \\
    \hline
    Women & & & 21,500 \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    Total & 48,000 & & 50,500 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vskip3ex
  \begin{tabular}{|| c | c | c V{2}c ||}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|| c ||}{{\bf Residents of Preston City}} \\
    \hline
          & Employed & Unemployed & Total \\
    \hline
    Men & 27,000 & & \\
    \hline
    Women & & & 21,500 \\
    \hlineB{2}
    Total & 48,000 & & 50,500 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `\setcellgapes{3pt}`?  I got an error when I had `TikZ` compile the code without this in the preamble.

Comment: It defines a vertical padding of 3pt at the top and bottom of cells (you surely noticed vertical spacing is often too tight. This is one of the ways to circumvent this problem). You make it active for a given table adding  `\makegapedcells` before the table begins. Normally, it has nothing to do with TikZ.